# fetch data from model that is called in loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller function in CodeIgniter that looks like this:

```
$perm = $this->job_m->getIdByGroup();
foreach($perm as $pe=>$p)
{
    $pId  =  $p['id'];
    $result = $this->job_m->getDatapermission($pId);
}

$data['permission'] = $result;
```

What I need to do is list the data in the result in the view, but I get only the last value while using this method. How can I pass all the results to the view?

Comment: What is `$this->job_m->getDatapermission($pId);` returning. Do check my answer below. I'd like to modifying if I know what `$this->job_m->getDatapermission($pId);` returns. Array, Object, string or integer?

Answer (score 1):

Store it in an array. Like this:

```
foreach($perm as $pe=>$p){
   $result[] = $this->job_m->getDatapermission($p['id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because $result is not an array...

try this:

```
$result=array();
foreach($perm as $pe=>$p)
{
    $pId  =  $p['id'];
    $result[] = $this->job_m->getDatapermission($pId);
}

$data['permission'] = $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Note:

My answer uses a `counter` to enable the display of a single group result when needed.

Guessing from your need  to loop and display the value of $result, possibly, it is an array or object returned by $query->result(). Things could be a bit complex.

Example: if $perm is an array  of 5 items( or groups), the counter assigns keys 1 - 5 instead of 0 - 4 as would [] which could be misleading. Using the first view example, you could choose to display a single group value if you wants by passing it via a url segment. Making the code more flexible and reusable. E.g. You want to show just returns for group 2, in my example, $result[2] would do just that else next code runs. See my comments in the code.

```
$perm = $this->job_m->getIdByGroup();
$counter = 1; 
foreach($perm as $pe=>$p)
{
    $pId  =  $p['id'];
    $result[$counter] = $this->job_m->getDatapermission($pId);
$counter++;
}

$data['permission'] = $result;
```

#### As mentioned above Note:

I Added a Counter or Key so you target specific level. If the groups are:
Men, Women, Boys, Girls, Children; you'd know women is group two(2) If you desire to display values for just that group, you don't need to rewrite the code below. Just pass the group key would be as easy as telling it by their sequence. To display all the loop without restrictions, use the second view example. To use both, use an if statement for that.

```
###To access it you could target a specific level like 

if(isset($permission)){
    foreach($permission[2] as $key => $value){
        echo $value->columnname;
    }


###To get all results:

    foreach($permission as $array){
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            echo $value->columnname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `$result[] = ...;` like the other answers suggest? What makes you assume that `getDatapermission` returns an array?

Comment: Why else would you want to loop the value of $result if it is not an array? My answer does not have to be like other answers. If it has to, then it shouldn't be a new answer. My point is, if `$perm` is an array of 5 items( or groups), My counter assigns keys 1 - 5 instead of 0 - 4 as would []. That way, using my first view example, he could choose display a single group value if he wants. Making the code more flexible and reusable. Eg. He want to show just for group 2, in my example, $result[2] would do just that else next code runs. See my comments in the code.

Comment: `$result` will hold an array, but you assume `getDatapermission`returns an array too, resulting in a nested array. But `getDatapermission` may as well return a single record. The counter only adds overhead to the code. It doesn't provide any benefits. I mean what is the benefit of using `$permission[2]` instead of `$permission[1]`??

Comment: No, Since we don't have his model, we can only assume what returns. It could be an array or a string or an integer. He never spelt that out in his question. If it is a string, he could tweak the code. We only help, we don't write all codes. My codes are based on the assumption that getDatapermission($p['id'] is returning an object from $this->db->result(); I think it's fair at this time for the OP to tell us what getDatapermission($p['id'] returns. He's been silent or absent.